Is there a visual tool to debug Kotlin Sequence in IntelliJ IDEA similar to Java Stream debug with Stream Trace?
I code in Kotlin and use Sequence a lot. I use IntelliJ IDEA and there is nice visual debug tool to introspect your Java Stream processing steps. Is there anything similar for Sequences?

There is Kotlin Sequence Debugger plugin and it states its features are a part of the main Kotlin plugin since 2019.1. But I don't see anything like this in my IDE.

I have only found 11 months old ticket asking for the same feature. I cannot understand why would JetBrains add support for Java but not four their own language.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-335333/Debugger-Enable-Stream-trace-for-Kotlin-collections-too

In the ticket you linked it says: "The existing Stream trace debugger works for Java Streams and Kotlin sequences [...]". The ticket is about adding this functionality also to collections, implying it already works for sequences. Have you tried it?

Please do not edit your question in a way that invalidates answers that were already given. I reverted the question to its previous state. If you want to ask something else you can always ask a new question.

It's part of the "Java Stream Debugger" plugin that comes bundled and pre-installed with IntelliJ IDEA.
Despite the name it also works on Kotlin Sequences:
While on a breakpoint in a sequence chain during debugging, in the Debug window click the More button displayed as three vertical dots:

In the following popup select "Trace Current Stream Chain":

That may be grayed out in the beginning, but for me, it automatically enabled after a couple of seconds.
When clicking on it a new window pops up with the sequence explained:

